# Why are standard libraries always so complex?

Tags: c++, c

this might be a strange question, but I don't quite understand this. When I look at let's say string.h, I really have no idea what I'm even looking at... Maybe I'm just inexperienced or something, but those files look nothing like a header file I've ever written.

I could write my own string implementation and it would be so much shorter and more readable than this file I'm looking at here...

So basically I'm just wondering what's going on here that makes it necessary to write all this long and complex code.

Edit: oke thanks for the responses, I get the point. It's kind of what I expected, but it's nice to get some confirmation:p

Comment: `string.h` is C code, so you may want to change the tag.

Comment: It's not really about string.h specifically though, more general

Comment: They are usually written to 1) compile fast 2) execute *really* fast 3) behave well with crap input 4) correctly handle all corner cases. Readability was never a concern.

Comment: Your "much shorter and more readable own string implementation" wouldn't satisfy the requirements established in the standard library language specification. So we'd be comparing apples to oranges: a library which must satisfy standards and thus guarantee a certain behaviour in a wide variety of cases, and your own personal pet library, which would basically do whatever you want.

Comment: At whoever put this question on hold: just because the author expresses an opinion, does not mean that the question is opinion-based. There are perfectly clear, good answers to this question. Must we really close everything whenever we think that there might be some vague reason to do so?

Comment: @LeeWhite: I totally agree; this is a question that we have all probably had at one point or another, and the phenomenon is universal enough not to be "opinion-based".

Comment: When you talk about standard libraries - it is the most used and generic code that everyone uses. One has to take care of all the coding conventions strictly so that the library code does not make any clash with user code or any other library code. e.g. the global variables are well defined so that there is minimum possibility of collision with your variable names. The calling conventions are well specified sometimes to avoid confusion. All this makes it a piece of complex looking code, which in reality it is not.

Comment: It is opinion-based, because the OP has the opinion that string.h is always unreadable. That isn't true, it will look completely different from compiler to compiler. Looking at the compiler I'm currently using, string.h is just 80 lines, most of them function prototypes. There's a bit of compatibility goo, but overall, it is not complex at all and easy to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Driving a car is (arguably) extremely easy, compared to how complicated an engine looks on the inside.

Libraries such as these are meant to be easy to use, but what's behind the scenes might not always be easy to understand. You're better off using the actual documentation for such libraries.